# Javascript How to create and use blob with pure binary data

Tags: javascript, blob

I have a pure Uint8Array I want to save into a blob
I can create the blolb with any type ( 'text/plain', application/octet-stream, etc ) ..

```
var a_blob = new Blob(Uint8Array,{type: whatever});
```

Later to test the results I have:

```
this.read_blob = function (blob)  {
var reader = new FileReader();        
reader.onloadend =  function (evt) 
{ var full_buffer = evt.target.result;    }
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);    
}
```

I had stored 1 219 2 0 values (4 values using Uint32Array) and I have cheked all is right.

Now, i have : (I want to check the blob values)

```
var data  = new Uint32Array (full_buffer,0,4);
```

And I have : 
0: 808464433
1: 809054514
2: 808464432
3: 808464432
????????????

If I use :

```
var data  = new Uint8Array (full_buffer,0,4);
```

I have :
[49,48,48,48,50,49,57,48,48,...] which are the ascii codes for 1 0 0 0 2 1 9 0 ....
( the string representation of my values....)

What am I doing bad ? 
Maybe the blob is not really saved as pure binary data ?
Is fullbuffer a binary string object ?
Have I to use a specific type ?
Have I to read the buffer in a different way ?
Have to create a Uint8Array asociating full_buffer indivudual data in a loop ?

Comment: If you believe your solution will be helpful to others in the future, you should answer your own question (not edit your question with the solution). There may be a wait time before you can self-answer, though.

Comment: Please, move your answer out of your question and into an answer. I'll upvote it!

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Blob) explains : To create a blob you have to use

blob = new Blob(part,type);
part = An Array of data objects to put into the new Blob object.

So the fix (not easy to discover because oneself are seeing one and another time arrays, bufferarray, typedarrays.... and you feel confused ) is to use [] brackets to create on the fly an array of element/s.

So instead of :

```
var a_blob = new Blob(Uint8Array,{type: whatever});
```

use

```
var a_blob = new Blob([Uint8Array],{type: whatever});
```

Believe me, after a lot of web searching you can see posts where you can see a blob creation with and without the brackets